# Unable to add a new availability zone to an existing load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, availability-zone

Had created a Load balancer to added some EC2 instances to them and everything is working as expected. I cannot *add* a new availability zone to this load balancer. I need to add the new zone as an ec2 instance type that I want is not available in the zone that is already in the Load Balancer.

- When i try to add it from the command line, the Load Balancer itself is not recognized.
- From the UI, the edit instances on the load balancer is greyed out.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Hemanth

Comment: what kind of load balancer did you create? Application or Network?

Comment: Can you share the command your using, region, AWS config file for CLI and screenshot of your console with information about your ELB?

Comment: @gtosto. Its a TCP Load Balancer.

Comment: This is the command I ran to add a zone to the lb:aws elb enable-availability-zones-for-load-balancer --load-balancer-name va-elb-app-01 --availability-zones us-east-1b --region us-east-1. The error i got was : An error occurred (LoadBalancerNotFound) when calling the EnableAvailabilityZonesForLoadBalancer operation: There is no ACTIVE Load Balancer named 'va-elb-app-01'

Comment: On the side note, this is a programming QA site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add or remove an Availability Zone from a Network Load Balancer (TCP Load Balancer) after it's been created. You are going to have to create a new one.

From the [AWS official docs for Network Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/network-load-balancers.html#availability-zones):

> You enable one or more Availability Zones for your load balancer when you create it. You cannot enable or disable Availability Zones for a Network Load Balancer after you create it.